# Why is this python class instance hashable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, hash, python-2.x

This is pertaining to python 2.x

In the following class, if we subclass "***object***", I understand the methods are inherited in the derived class Foo which includes `__hash__` (can see this by printing dir(Foo() )

Hence calling hash(Foo()) calls the magic method `__hash__` and gives us a hash value.

However, if we don't subclass "***object***", resulting in dir(Foo()) not listing out the `__hash__` method, so then why do we still get a hash value in python2?

*I believe in python3 this problem has been addressed since the methods from the* "object*" class are inherited by default.

```
#class Foo(object) Works since __hash__ is available in the base class 
class Foo:  #Why does this work? 
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
a = Foo()
print dir(a) # No __hash__ magic method
print hash(a) 
# Expecting an error like non-hashable or __hash__ not implemented 
# or something similar
```

Comment: Hint: `id(a)` still works. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192418/hash-function-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old-style classes are weird. Officially, instances of old-style classes aren't wholly instances of their class, they're all instances of type `instance`. [The `instance` type defines `__hash__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/classobject.c#L2202) (`tp_hash` is the C level slot that's equivalent to `__hash__` for C defined types), so even though it's not defined on your instance directly, nor on the class that created it, it finds `__hash__` on the `instance` type itself through weird and terrible magic (actually, the magic is in how it manages to use your class's features at all, given that its type is `instance`).

You can see this in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> class Foo: pass

>>> Foo().__hash__  # Same basic error for Foo.__hash__ too
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
----> 1 Foo().__hash__

AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute '__hash__'
>>> type(Foo())
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(Foo()).__hash__
<slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'instance' objects>
```

This works even though the instance itself can't see `__hash__` because "special methods" (those documented special methods that begin and end with double underscores) are looked up on the type, not the instance, so `__hash__` is found on `instance` itself. At the C level, [`hash(x)` is doing the equivalent of `type(x).__hash__(x)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/object.c#L1107) (it's a little more complicated because it won't use the default `__hash__` implementation if `__eq__` has a custom definition, but that's the general idea).

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.