# my Python multiprocesses are apparently not independent

Tags: python, random, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing

I have a very specific problem with python parallelisation let's see if I can explain it,

I want to execute a function `foo()` using the multiprocessing library for parallelisation.

```
# Creation of the n processes, in this case 4, and start it
threads = [multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(i)) for i in range(n)]
for th in threads:
    th.start()
```

The `foo()` function is a recursive function who explores a tree in depth until one specific event happens. Depending on how it expands through the tree, this event can occur in a few steps, for example 5 or even in millions. The tree nodes are a set of elements and in each step I select a random element from this set with `rand_element = random.sample(node.set_of_elements,1)[0]` and make a recursive call accordingly to them, i.e., two different random elements have different tree paths.

The problem is that for some unknown reason, the processes apparently does not behave independently. For example, if I run 4 processes in parallel, sometimes they return this result.

```
1, Number of steps: 5
2, Number of steps: 5
3, Number of steps: 5
4, Number of steps: 5
```

that is to say, all the processes take the "good path" and ends in a very few steps. On the other hand, other times it returns this.

```
1, Number of steps: 6516
2, Number of steps: 8463
3, Number of steps: 46114
4, Number of steps: 56312
```

that is to say, all the processes takes "bad paths". I haven't had a single execution in which at least one takes the "good path" and the rest the "bad path".

If I run `foo()` multiple times sequentially, more than a half of execution ends with less than 5000 steps, but in concurrency I don't see this proportion, all the processes ends either fast or slow.
How is it possible?

Sorry if I can't give you more precise details about the program and execution, but it is too big and complex to explain here.

Comment: You may be having some issues with `random` pseudo-random values. I would suggest printing the node they chose to see if there is some kind of pattern. If that is the case, using current time in microseconds multiplied by the number of process should give you a unique seed for each process. Remember that only the time in this case may be or may not be equal (that's why I'm multiplying by the number of process).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried it with multiple seeds, I just tried this one you mention and the result is the same, all the processes takes same paths. Do you see the creation and launch of the multiprocesses okay?

Comment: It looks okey to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, I post it in case someone finds it helpful

The problem was that at some point inside `foo()`, I have used the `my_set.pop()` method instead of `set.remove(random.sample (my_set, 1) [0])`. The first one, `my_set.pop()` doesn't actually return a random element. In Python 3.6 sets have a concrete order like lists, the key is that the established order is generated randomly, so, to return a (pseudo)random element, the `my_set.pop()` method, always returns the first element. The problem was that in my case, all processes share that order, so `my_set.pop()` returns the same first element in all of them.

Comment: You should note my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `collections.OrderedDict` (or another ordered data structure) rather than `set` if your program cares about item order (as `random.sample()` does, for example). Even in Python 3.7 and later, at the time of this writing, `set`s are [documented as unordered collections](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), so they should not be used if the order in which items are inserted or enumerated is important to your program.

With `set`, you should not expect items to be inserted or enumerated in any particular order, even in a pseudorandom order.

See also:

- [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/)
- [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855489/815724